# Remember how variable/param assignment is done

Tags: vimrc

It seems quite tedious for me to remember how various settings are assigned, and so I find myself looking at `:h` or google or posting here to figure out how each setting is assigned (or just doing trial and error and using all possible combinations). For example, take the following two commands:

```
 autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set filetype=markdown
 autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt colorscheme OceanicNext
```

Why is the first command using `=` for assignment and the second one doesn't use anything (other than a space). At least to me (though admittedly I'm very new to vim), it seems there isn't much rhyme or reason as to the consistency of assignment (for example, why not just use `set [var]=[value]` for everything?). Is there a way to help remember which is which, or it really just comes down to practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pressing `K` immediately shows help for the word under cursor (in fact, it execs `:h 'keywordprg'`, but the standard `ftplugin` sets its value to `:help` for "vim" files).
2. All `:`-commands have standardized structure: `[range]command[!] [parameters]`. Here `set` and `colorscheme` are commands, and so they both are followed by space. `filetype=markdown` is a parameter. Its format depends on the leading command (`:set`). If you don't remember it you should read `:h :set`.

Comment: thanks, could you please explain the `K immediately` thing?

Comment: Oh, I see. When in normal mode, and my cursor is above a term, I can press Shift-k (capital K) to view help for that word.

Comment: @David542 I mean it's Normal mode command, not Ex-command.